# Eliminating character e280a8 from a Java String

Tags: java, json, oracle, character-encoding, byte

My application takes a Java string and puts it in a JSON response, it works on IE but for some reason on Chrome and Firefox I don't see the data on the page, I don't get any console errors and I do get the Response Object with the ability to examine it on Firebug and Chrome debugging tools.

I am working with Java 6, and the String in question is created from a CLOB column from an Oracle DB:

> 4:42 PM<

This is the hex code of the above String as it is on Oracle:

> 34,3a,34,32,20,50,4d,e2,80,a8,3c

As you can see, between the "M" (4d) and the "<" (3c) we have the values e2,80,a8, which according to UTF-8 is a line separator (e280a8), I've tested my application by adding only the substring until the "M" and it works on all browsers, but the moment I include one more character it breaks. So it is safe to say that the character is causing the issue.

The Java console outputs the string as:

> 4:42 PMâ€¨<

And its byte values as:

> 52,58,52,50,32,80,77,-30,-128,-88,60

Since I know that there should not be a line break or anything else between the "M" and "<", I think the solution would be to scrub that character, but `desc = desc.replaceAll("â€¨", "");` doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bytes are in UTF-8, and it is the Unicode line separator `"\u2028"`. You are right.

```
desc = desc.replace("\u2028", "");
```

Comment: desc = desc.replace("\u2028", ""); works, but BufferedReader still leaves the character.

Comment: Aha, mixed it up with Unicode NEL, `\u0085`, an originally EBCDIC linefeed. Will clean the answer for others. THANKS